# Mac OS X libcurl dylib compatibility version

Tags: macos, libcurl, dylib

My application builds and runs fine on 10.6. I have Base SDK set to 10.6 and Mac OS X Deployment Target set to 10.5.

My application uses the system libcurl.dylib — instead of adding the dylib to the project, I just add `-lcurl` to the linker flags in build settings. (Though I have tried it both ways.)

When I launch the application on 10.5.8, I get the following error

> Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Applications/My Application.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication
>
> Reason: Incompatible library version:
>
> MyApplication requires version 6.0.0 or
>   later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides
>   version 5.0.0

Sure enough, if I `otool -L` the application's binary, I get the following for libcurl:

> /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)

Is there any way around this, or should I just statically link my own libcurl build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Base SDK to 10.5 as well?

```
$ otool -L /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    ...]
$ otool -L /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    [...]
```