# Use 3rd party libraries in mac OS X environment

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dynamic-linking, install-name-tool

I am upgrading a legacy mac OS X build environment (C++ code) and trying to find the 'right way' to handle third parties libraries (all of them are open source libraries).
We currently support multiple mac OS x versions which use (dynamic link) each OS version's default third parties libraries (located at /usr/lib) it causes compatibility errors and therefore I look for a better way to do it.

On windows environment we use a redistributable package similar to the visual studio's version to prevent such errors, I did not find anything similar here.

Solutions I have in mind are compile them manually or take them from the MacOSX-SDK manually and use install_name_tool to enforce our dylibs and applications to use these libraries.

In the following link I found a similar solution:
[In Xcode, how do I link a dynamic library (libcurl) so that the app also works on older versions of the Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342046/in-xcode-how-do-i-link-a-dynamic-library-libcurl-so-that-the-app-also-works-o)

But all of them 'smells' as a bad idea.

Comment: Which libraries, specifically?  Distributing system libraries with your application is likely to be problematic from a legal stand point.  For third-party libraries, you can compile them yourself and put them in your application bundles using `@rpath`.

Comment: All of them are open source libraries, I can compile them by myself, but I am not sure if it is the right way to do it. Is there a way to put them in an application bundle directly from the macOS-sdk?

Comment: I hate to ask the question again, but, what libraries, specifically?  And you're not talking about libraries in the SDK, but libraries installed with the system in `/usr/lib`, right?  I wouldn't assume that those libraries would work correctly when copied to different versions of the operating system.

Comment: For now I am trying to solve the issue for libapr, libaprutils but also libssl and libcurl.
I did talk about the libraries in the SDK, this is why I searched for something similar to the 'redistributable package' in windows environment, when I didn't find such solution, I thought about taking the libraries from the SDK and put them in a lib folder inside the application's directory then use install_name_tool to enforce my application to use these libraries

Comment: Minor note: These libraries aren't in the SDK.  I've looked, but the SDK only has header files, so there is literally nothing for you to copy out of the SDK.

Comment: But on the point of the question: I don't really see a way around you compiling some of these yourself.  OpenSSL, in particular, is deprecated, breaks binary compatibility all the time, and is generally riddled with flaws.  So the only good solution, if you are using OpenSSL on OS X or Windows, is to compile it yourself.  Since Curl depends on OpenSSL (if you build it that way), then this applies to Curl as well, transitively.

Comment: @DietrichEpp
This is the path I found the libraries inside the SDK:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/
I didn't find information about these libraries in the documnatation but it seems these are the same as the libraries in a regular mac 10.9 (at /usr/lib)

The reason I try to avoid compiling it myself is, as you mentioned yourself regarding libssl and libcurl: there is a dependency between some of the libraries.
Taking these libraries from the SDK or from a 'redistributable package' should eliminate such errors

Comment: I feel like I'm repeating myself because this is the third time I've said it, but you seem to be ignoring me when I say this.  **There is no guarantee that these libraries will even work on other systems.** Also, do you actually see any libraries in there?  I don't, but then again I'm looking at the 10.12 SDK.  I see files like `libz.tbd`.

Comment: In SDK 10.9 they do appear, these libs are the same as the one at /usr/lib,
There isn't any guaranty they will work, but these are the libs which were used to build and link the application, therefore I believe they will work. but the fact they do not appear in 10.12 means this solution is not good because it will stop working when I upgrade to 10.12 SDK